# how to set one server for wso2 analytics and one sever for wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to have a server that visualize api data from my wso2 api manager
can anyone help me pls?
Thanx

```
      `enter code here`
```

Comment: What did you encounter / what did you already try? There is documentation on the profiles (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/product-profiles/) that might help you out. This can be applied to EI as well.

Comment: @JustLudo
Hi.I want to seperate wso2 analytics from wso2 api manager that api manager statics sent to wso2 analytics located on anaother server .but I dont hava any clue

Comment: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/mi-analytics/setting-up-mi-analytics/ <--- something like this?

Comment: @JustLudo I am not looking for HA .one server for apim and one server for analytics and I am working on version 3.2.0

Comment: Then I don't know.

Comment: @JustLudo tnx sir

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the WSO2 API Manager in a single server and the Analytics in another server and configure both API Manager and Analytics TOML/Yaml configurations to communicate and send data.

Follow the `Standard Setup` steps provided in [WSO2 API Manager Docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#standard-setup) for more detailed steps and configurations.